# Getting a list of the published posts

Tags: plugins, posts

I would like to get a list of the posts published in WP in every category with the published date and the last modified date.

I've tried to achieve this result through a Plugin but it's completely not mature. So I am also ready to write some code.

I've googled and found this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) `wp_get_recent_posts`

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => ,
    'exclude' => ,
    'meta_key' => ,
    'meta_value' =>,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
?>
```

But a big question is where can I put this code and how to get the date? Should I create a micro plugin?

Comment: Do you mean, you like posts, status `draft` about all categories in a time window of his published date? Or you will get the published and modified date from the post, after you have the post. At first you get a list of post, then have each post this data. You get this via additional function.

Comment: @bueltge: and which is the name of the additional function?

Comment: See the answer much more whitespace for a solid return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `wp_get_recent_posts()`do you retrieve the most recent posts. For meta data, like published date and modified date use additional functions.

For the published date is [`the_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) helpful.

For the modified date use [`the_modified_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date).

The functions are a part of the Template Tags, useful for Theme and direct output. But she have also parameters to get the values for custom echo.

A small example:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) 
             . '">' .   $recent["post_title"] 
             . '</a> Published on ' 
             . the_date( $echo = FALSE ) 
             . ', Modified on ' 
             . the_modified_date( $echo = FALSE ) 
             . '</li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

The example is not ready to use, especially translation ready. Enhance with the i18n functions from WordPress to create a solid, translatable and sanitized result with the helper functions for this topic, like `esc_attr_e()`, `esc_attr__()` and `printf()`.

If you don't like to use the parameters on the functions, more short. Then use the functions, there was used inside the Template Tags - `get_the_modified_date()` and `get_the_date()`.